# Laravel 5.1 Query Builder where AND where

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5.1, query-builder

*Hello could you help me with laravel 5.1 query builder.*

**I want to create a query that has where AND where.**

*I have already read the whole documentation but i could get any answer.*

This is my query:

```
 DB::table('connected_users')
        ->where('user_id',$user->id)
        ->where('connected_id',$id)
        ->update(['status' => '2']);
```

This is my route Code:

```
Route::post('teacher/{id}/connection/approve','ConnectController@aproveConnection');
```

This is my Laravel Controller Code:

```
public function aproveConnection($id){

   $user = Auth::user();

   DB::table('connected_users')

      ->where('user_id',$user->id)
      ->where('connected_id',$id)
      ->update(['status' => '2']);

       return Redirect::back();
}
```

This is my POST form:

```
<form method="POST" action="../teacher/{{ $pend_user->id }}/connection/approve">
   {!! csrf_field() !!}
   <input type="submit" value="Αποδοχή Φίλου">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using multiple `where()`'s is the equivilent of an AND operator. Query will only pass if both `where()` clauses meet your search criteria.

Comment: Both of them meet my search criteria i checked that a 100 times. i also tried to echo the variable's value so i can know if its right.

Comment: try this:
`$connected = DB::table('connected_users')->where('user_id',$user->id)->where('connected_id',$id)->get();`
and then update each of them:
`foreach($connected as $something){
          $something->update(['status' => 2]);
}`